# PHP run function in class

Tags: php, class, function

I have some code like this inside a file `script.php`:

```
class ABC
{
    public function sampleName() { do something}
}
```

Now if I run

```
php script.php
```

from command line it doesn't do anything.  I thought it would execute the function. Do I have to call the funciton `sampleName` somewhere inside the file? If so, how do I do this?

After the class ends should I say `$this->SampleName()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

instantiate your class -> call function:

```
class ABC
{
    function __construct { some code }
    public function sampleName() { do something}
}

$abc = new ABC(); // new instance of ABC
$abc->sampleName(); // we've done something
```

Comment: thank you, i understand it now, but if i run php script.php now, it should do something right?

Comment: yeah i know:) i am using command line to run this..i will fix this..

Answer (score 0):

[Reading the manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php) also helps to understand the basics of OOP in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

After the class closing brace, create the object of the class.

```
$abc = new ABC();
$output = $abc->sampleName();
print $output;
```